# Adobe AIR camera slow

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, camera

I am having issues with using the camera on *Adobe AIR mobile devices*.

The performance of the camera is ok on newer phones, but on galaxy s2 for example it is impossible to use. I am using the **camera** like this:

```
 _camera = Camera.getCamera("0");
    if (_camera != null)
    {

//      _video = new Video();
        _video = new Video(_camera.width, _camera.height);
//      _video.width = _cameraHeight;
        _video.width = _cameraHeight;
        _video.height = Starling.current.nativeStage.fullScreenWidth;
        _camera.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, onCameraActivity);
        _camera.setMode( _video.width,_video.height, 30 );
        _video.attachCamera(_camera);
        _videoContainer.addChild(_video);
    }
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

EDIT: The problem is that the framerate drops to around 1 on Galaxy S2 and the app crashes. On my galaxy S3 it works around 30fps. I also tried uploading the video to the GPU on every frame using

```
flash.display3D.textures.Texture(image.texture.base).uploadFromBitmapData(bmd);
```

it gets better on my galaxy s3 then, fps is around 50-60, but on galaxy s2 still terrible and unusable(around 1 fps)

Comment: What do you mean by "it is impossible to use"? You ask a question, but provide next-to-no details of what the problem is.

Comment: Hey Josh, i added more info.

Comment: What do you need the Camera for? Is this something that could be offloaded onto `CameraUI`? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraUI.html

Comment: As an afterthought, you should also avoid using `Video` on mobile projects (it is rendered using the CPU which is very slow on mobile)

Comment: Thank you Josh for the recommendation, but i must use Camera and not CameraUI because i have to display a transparent overlay image over the camera. Is there something i can replace the Video with?

Comment: maybe if i would draw the camera to bitmap data every frame instead the Video?

Comment: Writing, reading, and rendering bitmaps is still extremely slow on mobile when doing it that often. I have never tried, but can you display the camera feed using `StageVideo`? That is the recommended method of showing video on mobile

Comment: Thanks again Josh, but this is also not working because it seems that StageVideo is not supported on Android. This really sucks for AIR

Comment: `StageVideo` *is* supported on Android (at least on 4.0+ which I've tested, hit or miss on 2.3.x). I use it all the time (I have three apps in the Play Store currently using it with two more on the way). Make sure `renderMode` is `gpu` or `direct`. Also make sure you have masked your application. `StageVideo` resides *under* the display list, so you have to mask a hole in your app to see it.

Comment: are you using camera in your projects? because i read somewhere that attachCamera is not supported on Android, but for the love of god i can't find it now :) Also I'm using Starling and i don't have ANYTHING on my nativeStage

Comment: yep, just tested its definitely not working on android. also i am having the render mode as direct and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> in my descriptor. testing on galaxy s3. please read more carefully next time

Comment: ok, i found the page where it clearly says StageVideo is not supported on Android. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html#attachCamera() Can you back up what you are saying with a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually using Starling, this is what I've used before (project about half an year old, don't know if things changed that much):

```
camera = Camera.getCamera();
camera.setLoopback(false);
camera.setMode(640, 640, 15);
var cropping:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, getLowerPowerOfTwo(camera.width), getLowerPowerOfTwo(camera.height));
webcamVideo = new WebcamVideo(  camera, 
                                new Rectangle(
                                    (camera.width - cropping.width) * .5,
                                    (camera.height - cropping.height) * .5,
                                    cropping.width,
                                    cropping.height),
                                false,
                                 WebcamVideo.DRAW_BITMAPDATA|WebcamVideo.UPLOAD_FROM_BITMAPDATA);
```

The frame rate is set to 15, but if you try you can see that the result is not that bad. And I've set it to 15, because of the fact that I was testing on an old HTC Sensation (3 years old), S2 and another one old that I forgot. You can check the hardware and boost up if needed. On HTC One it works like a charm at 30.

Give it a try, I hope it helps! :)

Comment: If you go into WebcamVideo code you can see that it is basically doing the same thing i did in in my original question(flash.display3D.textures.Texture(image.texture.base).uploadFromBitmapData(bmd);
).

Comment: Yeah but it does it in a very clean and optimized way :) It worths trying in my opinion..