# AS3, AIR, Android, Camera UI. It's possible to customize?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, user-interface, air

I'm using the AIR's "CameraUI" functionality.

I need to put some branded graphic design. It must overlay the camera capture, and its components.

There is some way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this that I know of is to use a native extension to get the raw camera data and create your own UI using the BitmapData video frame buffers.

It works reasonably well from my experience.

Comment: No need of extension - just get rid of CameraUI and use Camera and Video :) Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758912/adobe-air-camera-slow/22837942

Comment: Hi Michael, do you mean somnething like this? https://code.google.com/p/diadraw-air-camera-native-extension/

Comment: Hi Andrey Popov, your recommendation refers to avoid using CameraUI, and instead use Starling + Camera + Video ? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah you can definitely get the view out of Camera/Video however you can't really use that to actually capture an image. 

Miguel: Yes something like that is what I was referring to. That one is pretty good, and there are a few other ones around. I've developed my own here: http://distriqt.com/product/air-native-extensions/camera

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm interested to buy your camera ANE http://distriqt.com/product/air-native-extensions/camera

Hi have some important questions before buy:

1. Can I put branding/desing over the camera image?

2. Can I start/stop the camera from my code (start record with a button, stop record after XX time)?

3. Can I save the recorded video to an specific location of my hard drive?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Miguel, I just wrote back to your email, but basically the video recording to a native file hasn't been completed yet, only image capture and video frames. You can however use the frames in the normal display list or as a starling texture as they are just bitmap data. We're hoping to complete the video record function in the coming weeks.